# Node Addons (C++) in Electron

Tags: electron, node.js-addon

I'm trying to integrate C++ with HTML using Electron and Node JS.But I'm confused by the NODE_MODULE_VERSION.
I have a binding.gyp like examples.

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ "src/hello.cc" ],
      "include_dirs": [
      "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and a hello.cc

```
// hello.cc
#include <node.h>

namespace demo {

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world"));
}

void init(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, init)

}  // namespace demo
```

and after node-gyp configure build,they run well with node

```
const addon = require('./package/build/Release/addon');
addon.hello();
```

But when I combined it with electron,there is something wrong.
[image]

I have read the APIs of both electron and nodejs.Some told me to install nvm to change nodejs's version,and others advice me to install electron-build.I tried,but they don't work.(I think it will be strange if they work).
I think what's the matter is the version of nodejs.But my node is v7.7.4!So,how can i update the version of modules...
thanks~

Comment: It's the first time for me to ask question...seems like there are a lot of problems...

Comment: There doesnt seem to be anything wrong with the question.. formatting and editing revisions happen all the time here

Comment: Really?I'm afrid of that masters can't understand me...

Comment: as long as the question follows [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it will do fine

Comment: how do you build it with `node-gyp`? you should follow electron guide: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md#manually-building-for-electron

Answer (score 3):

As @pergy mentioned you should build with --taget option pointing to the correct iojs(node) version used in electron.

see a working sample(windows) here. 
https://github.com/weliwita/electron-edge-sample/tree/42996881/node-addons-c-in-electron

Answer (score -1):

I have posted a git project here:https://github.com/anurag2911/angular-electron-nodeaddon
This is a simple angular-electron-nodeaddon project.This is a working example of how to write c++ node addons and use them in electron.